# Variadic macro warning

Tags: c++, macros, variadic

In C++, variadic macros `require at least one argument for the '...'`. Consider the function: `FOO(a, b, ...);` What should I do in case I want both of these calls to be correct and warning-free? `FOO(5, 4, "gamma"); FOO(5, 4);` I'm using the `--pedantic` flag, so just suppressing the warning is not an option.

The second one gives a compile-time warning mentioned above. I considered this:

Changing the definition to `FOO(a, ...);` and splitting the `__VA_ARGS__` variable (which stands for ...) into `b` and, if present, into the rest. So the function calls would look like: `FOO(5, "4gamma");` and `FOO(5, "4");` This, I think, is not a good option because the splitting is not efficient and the function declaration will not require the `b` argument, even though its mandatory.

Are there any better ways to get a warning-free compilation?

Comment: Why are you using a macro?  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: A variadic function template is your solution.

Comment: @DeiDei Could you please elaborate on function templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I wholly agree that if at all possible, variadic functions or function templates should be used, the question also shows some misunderstanding about what can and cannot be done with macros, so in this answer I'm going to pretend functions are not an option.

> Changing the definition to `FOO(a, ...);` and splitting the `__VA_ARGS__` variable (which stands for ...) into `b` and, if present, into the rest.

Yes.

> So the function calls would look like: `FOO(5, "4gamma");` and `FOO(5, "4");`

No. Continue the invocation as `FOO(5, 4, "gamma");` and `FOO(5, 4);`. In the first case, `__VA_ARGS__` is `4, "gamma"`. In the second case, `__VA_ARGS__` is `4`.

If you need to extract `, "gamma"` from the former, that can be done by the preprocessor. It requires an upper limit on the amount of parameters, but you can increase this to pretty much any number you like. It's ugly though.

If `__VA_ARGS__` contains no commas, the extraction is trivial:

```
#define COMMA_TRAILING_ARGS_0(a)
```

If you know `__VA_ARGS__` contains at least one comma, you can use

```
#define COMMA_TRAILING_ARGS_1(a, ...) , __VA_ARGS__
```

And you can detect which of these to use, up to a certain upper limit of macro arguments:

```
#define ARG16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, ...) _16
#define HAS_COMMA(...) ARG16(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, )
```

Combined:

```
#define COMMA_TRAILING_ARGS_0(a)
#define COMMA_TRAILING_ARGS_1(a, ...) , __VA_ARGS__

#define ARG16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, ...) _16
#define HAS_COMMA(...) ARG16(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,)

#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT_(a, b) CONCAT(a, b)

#define FOO(a, ...) BAR(a CONCAT_(COMMA_TRAILING_ARGS_, HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__)) (__VA_ARGS__))

FOO(5, 4, x, q);    // expands to BAR(5, x, q);
FOO(5, 4, "gamma"); // expands to BAR(5, "gamma");
FOO(5, 4);          // expands to BAR(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

- you can get rid of this macro because macros are evil and replace it with template or something else
- you can define two macros: `FOOs` - with many arguments and `FOO` - with just two argumets
- you can use [gcc `##__VA_ARGS__` extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) (assuming that you are using gcc or compatible compiler)

Comment: But that means I would have to `FOO(5, 4); FOOs(5, 4, "gamma");`, which is something slightly different than what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand your specific problem, but from what you've shown, it's much easier to use two overloaded functions.

```
void foo(int, int);
void foo(int, int, const std::string&);

foo(3, 4); // calls first
foo(3, 4, "hello"); // calls second
```

Or maybe even:

```
void foo(int, int, const std::string& = "");
```

On the other hand if you can use C++11:

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(int, int, const Args&... args); // google variadic templates
```

A parameter pack (`args`) can consist of *zero or more* arguments.